# Is it possible to use a string to type a Template in C#?

Tags: c#

Can I use a string to type a Templated method in C#?

I would like to do something like this (Juste an example code)

`string str = "MyProject.MyType";
dynamic obj = jsonObject.ToObject<str>();`

I tried to use `Type.GetType()` to get the type from my string, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: It is really unclear what you want. Is your goal to get an instance of 'MyType'? Where does the idea of a list come from?

Comment: Don't use generic method if you don't know type at compile time. There should be another non-generic method (or completely another approach) to specify type as parameter, e.g. `jsonObject.ToObject(Type.GetType(str));`

Comment: Nop, i know that part, but i would like to know how to use a string as a type.

Comment: @Sinatr I tried this, but got an error (`Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'Type'`)

Comment: @Loofer I've got a terrible english, sorry for that. I have a string like `"Project.ObjectToDeserializeType"` and I need to use it for my `jsonObject.ToObject<Type>()` method

Comment: What is `jsonObject`? Json.Net? You have to use [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject_1.htm) method (not sure, but should give you idea) (where you pass type **as parameter**) and not [generic method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx). Generic method (one with `<>`) require to know type in advance as a constant (you can use reflection, but it's another *complicated* story). You want to pass it as parameter, so you can not use `ToObject<>`.

Comment: @Sinatr You solved my problem, thank you !